# Connect 4: Drop function only works for two row

Tags: c++

```
const int N = 200;
const string usr1 = "o", usr2 = "x";
void updateBoard(string a[N][N], int c, int n, string xo) {
  int col = c - 1;
  int row = n - 1;
  for (int i = row; i >= 0; i--) {
    if ((a[i][col] == usr1) || (a[i][col] == usr2)) {
      a[i - 1][col] = xo;
    }
    if ((a[i][col] == " ")) {
      a[i][col] = xo;
    }
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong, It stops at the second row, when i try to drop at third, it rewrites the value on the second...
This happens:

```
| x |
| x |
```

Want this:

```
| x |
| o |
| x |
```

Comment: Well, try to explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) why there is a `i = 0;` inside the loop.

Comment: Also, why `a[i - 1][col]` is updated without checking if *that* spot (not the neighbour) is empty?

Comment: And `a[i - 1]` is invalid when `i` is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer... Here's the fixed function:

```
bool updateBoard(string board[N][N], int col, int n, string xo) {
  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (board[i][col - 1] == "-") {
      board[i][col - 1] = xo;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```